# Return foreach get value into PHP Function

Tags: php, function, foreach

i'm creating an PHP Function and i get one problem...

I can't set the foreach value into a variable inside the function.

My code is this...

**The array:**

```
$baremos_precios = array(
/* [baremo (id)] => [kilos_precio] => [kilos_hasta($key) => precio($value)] */
1 => array('kilos_precio' => array(
        /* kilos hasta => precio (sin IVA) */
        5 => 6.6,
        10 =>  7.76,
        20 => 11.03,
        30 => 14.79,
        40 => 17.13,
        50 => 19.46,
        60 => 21.79,
        70 => 24.12,
        80 => 26.46,
        90 => 28.8,
        100 => 31.14,
        120 => 35.8,
        140 => 40.47,
        160 => 45.14,
        180 => 49.83,
        200 => 54.2,
        225 => 56.4,
        250 => 58.59,
        275 => 63.77,
        300 => 68.94,
        325 => 74.1,
        350 => 79.28,
        375 => 84.45,
        400 => 89.62,
        425 => 94.79,
        450 => 99.96,
        475 => 105.12,
        500 => 108.08,
        550 => 110.07,
        600 => 113.08,
        650 => 117.02,
        700 => 125.53,
        750 => 134.03,
        800 => 142.52,
        850 => 151.02,
        900 => 159.53,
        950 => 168.02,
        1000 => 176.53,
        1001 => 0.16 // precio por cada kilo apartir de >1000, ex: 1100kg => 0.16 * 1100 = 176€ + IVA
        )
    )

);
```

And the function with foreach's

```
function obtener_precio($baremo, $kg){
    $precio = 0;
    foreach($baremos_precios AS $key => $value){
        if($key == $baremo) {

            foreach ($value['kilos_precio'] as $secondkey => $secondvalue) {
                $kilos_array = [$secondkey];
                if($kilos_array[0] == $kg){
                    $precio = $secondvalue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $precio;
}
```

Okay, now i'm trying this one...

```
echo obtener_precio(1, 200);
```

And from it' i want to get result ===> 54.2, but i always got 0

**Where is the problem?, Thanks!**

Answer (score 2):

That's because you forgot to pass `$baremos_precios` into the function itself, without which you can't reach it from within the function body (unless you use dirty `global` tricks). So you should have this:

```
function obtener_precio($baremos_precios, $baremo, $kg){
```

And to call:

```
echo obtener_precio($baremos_precios, 1, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$baremos_precios` is not defined in side the function

Use :

`function obtener_precio($baremos_precios, $baremo, $kg){`

And to call it like:

`echo obtener_precio($baremos_precios, 1, 200);`

===========================================================

Instead of this :

```
$kilos_array = [$secondkey];
if($kilos_array[0] == $kg){
   $precio = $secondvalue;
}
```

use :

```
if($secondkey == $kg){
   $precio = $secondvalue;
}
```

Better i will suggest you to change the complete foreach here :

```
foreach ($value['kilos_precio'] as $secondkey => $secondvalue) {
    $kilos_array = [$secondkey];
    if($kilos_array[0] == $kg){
        $precio = $secondvalue;
    }
}
```

to :

```
if(array_key_exists($kg,$value['kilos_precio'])){
    $precio = $value['kilos_precio'][$kg];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i used $kilos_array,,, because when i was build the foreach, i writed --> echo $secondvalue;, and it returned me a math result. :S

Comment: Thanks again!, everyday i learn some new ways to do the same :)

Answer (score 0):

if `$baremos_precios` is a global variable do this:

```
function obtener_precio($baremo, $kg){
  global $baremos_precios;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can pass array as argument

function obtener_precio($baremos_precios,$baremo, $kg){
    //global $baremos_precios;
    $precio = 0;
    foreach($baremos_precios AS $key => $value){
        if($key == $baremo) {

            foreach ($value['kilos_precio'] as $secondkey => $secondvalue) {

                if($secondkey  == $kg){
                    $precio = $secondvalue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $precio;
}
echo obtener_precio($baremos_precios,1, 200);

or you can use global variable 
function obtener_precio($baremo, $kg){
    global $baremos_precios;
    $precio = 0;
    foreach($baremos_precios AS $key => $value){
        if($key == $baremo) {

            foreach ($value['kilos_precio'] as $secondkey => $secondvalue) {

                if($secondkey  == $kg){
                    $precio = $secondvalue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $precio;
}
echo obtener_precio(1, 200);
```